# Convert Date with Angular 4, Jhipster 4.x

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a property on my object, I want to save a date with time

```
public fechaActualizacion?: any,
```

I initialize it like this:

```
this.oportunidad.fechaActualizacion = new Date();
```

But turning it into service gives me an error

```
 copy.fechaActualizacion = this.dateUtils.toDate(oportunidad.fechaActualizacion);
```

toDate:

```
function toDate(date) {
    if (date === undefined || date === null) {
        return null;
    }
    var dateParts = date.split(/\D+/);
    return new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2], dateParts[3], dateParts[4]);
};
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: t.split is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ZonedDateTime for your entity.

If you don't want time on your Angular views, you just have to apply date filter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `new Date()` you can use `new Date().toISOString().replace( 'Z', '' )`. That will fix the issue.

i.e.

```
this.oportunidad.fechaActualizacion = new Date();
```

will become

```
this.oportunidad.fechaActualizacion = new Date().toISOString().replace( 'Z', '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a Date object to a method that expects a string to build a Date object. There should be more explicit typing in calling code and in toDate().